# Cross-compiling a Conan package

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, conan, ninja

I'm writing a small C++ cross-platform library which uses CMake, Clang, Ninja and Conan. I've managed to cross-compile the library, but I'm having difficulties adding a Conan package. For a test, I've added [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) as a dependecy in conanfile like so:

*conanfile.py*

```py
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeDeps, CMakeToolchain

class App(ConanFile):
    name = "example_library"
    version = "1.0.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "fmt/9.0.0"
    default_options = {"fmt:shared": True}
```

And I've made two conan profiles:

*clanglinux*

```
[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=clang
compiler.version=14
build_type=Release

[env]
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja

[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja

[options]
[build_requires]
```

*clangwindows*

```
[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=clang
compiler.version=14
build_type=Release

[env]
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja

[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja

[options]
[build_requires]
```

When executing `conan install` for a native platform (in this case Windows) everything works as expected. However, when I try to cross-compile the dependency for Linux with `conan install . --build=missing -pr:h=clanglinux -pr:b=clangwindows`, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:231 (add_library):
  The install of the fmt target requires changing an RPATH from the build
  tree, but this is not supported with the Ninja generator unless on an
  ELF-based or XCOFF-based platform.  The CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH
  variable may be set to avoid this relinking step.
```

This error occurs after Conan's `build()` function get's called for the *fmt* package. It calls `cmake` with the following arguments:

```
cmake -G "Ninja"
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/Users/name.surname/.conan/data/fmt/9.0.0/_/_/build/048e14dd7a94fe623d3253718843fce321999150/build/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Users/name.surname/.conan/data/fmt/9.0.0/_/_/package/048e14dd7a94fe623d3253718843fce321999150" 
-DFMT_DOC="OFF" 
-DFMT_TEST="OFF" 
-DFMT_INSTALL="ON" 
-DFMT_LIB_DIR="lib"
-DFMT_OS="ON" 
-DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"
"C:\Users\name.surname\.conan\data\fmt\9.0.0\_\_\build\048e14dd7a94fe623d3253718843fce321999150\src"
```

As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), this command is specified in the *fmt* conanfile and I don't have a lot of control over it. But according to the error message, I should add `-DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON` argument to the command. Is there a way to achieve this?
Also, why is it necessary to set `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` variable, can it be avoided altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are using legacy integrations. You should be using ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain`` instead.

Comment: @drodri Thanks, I've switched to CMakeDeps and CMakeToolchain and updated the question.

Comment: I see, it is not an issue per-se of your code, but the ``fmt`` recipe in ConanCenter doesn't seem to be ready to cross-compile with Clang, or it could be something related to how Conan understand Clan in Windows (https://blog.conan.io/2022/10/13/Different-flavors-Clang-compiler-Windows.html). I think the first step is to make sure a simple "hello world" recipe can be cross-compiled with your setup, then if that works and fmt fails, check fmt. Please report an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan with your specific setup about your clang cross compiler in Windows->Linux

Comment: Got it, I've posted a question on Conan's github page: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/12467